# JavaMail API office365 IMAP AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed

Tags: outlook

HI all I need help please:

I Have https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
SCOPE:
https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send offline_access openid email

I have authorizationCode OK !!

All

NEXT generate refreshToken and OK too.
BUT:

[image]

The errror:

[image]

```
A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:732)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
    at com.dyalogo.testmsauth.Test2.leerCorreos(Test2.java:95)
    at com.dyalogo.testmsauth.Test2.main(Test2.java:64)
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

PLEASE HELP ME

I try connect to IMAP office365